# blazeds push message to all clients

Tags: push, blazeds

I have a bootstrapper that handles `sessionDestroyed`, `sessionCreated`, `ClientCreated`, `ClientDestroyed`, `MessageClientDestroyed`, `MessageClientCreated` events.

My aim is to send a disconnect message to all clients or all subscribed destinations.

So i need a push mechanism inside the service. I have tried to get messageService and `MessageBroker` but i got exception.

I have tried `messageBroker.routeMessageToService(msg,null)`;
 and `messageService.pushMessageToClients(msg,true)`; both is unsuccessful because i could not get messageService and messageBroker.

How can i get `MessageBroker` or `MessageService` in service clientDestroyed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
             String clientId = UUIDUtils.createUUID();
                MessageBroker msgBroker = MessageBroker.getMessageBroker(null);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msgBroker);
                AsyncMessage msg = new AsyncMessage();
                msg.setDestination(dest.destinationList.get(i));
                msg.setClientId(clientId);
                msg.setMessageId(UUIDUtils.createUUID());
                msg.setHeader("disconnected",0);
                msg.setBody(client.getId());
                msgBroker.routeMessageToService(msg, null);
```

this is my working code hope it helps to somebody.